# Add automatical offset between columns Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

How to add automatical offset between bootstrap columns?
For instance if there are `col-5` and `col-4` offset will be `3` and so on

Answer (score 0):

Add Class `justify-content-between` on `row`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-5">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/cx8gq30j/1/